# How to go through all possibilities efficiently?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have run into this problem before, but it hasn't been too important until now: going through all combinations given 3 or 4 variables. My current project is in Python, so here is an example:

```
def function(var1, var2, var3):
    if var1:
        if var2:
            if var3:
                foo(bar)
            else:
                bar(foo)
        else:
            if var3:
                ...
```

Even this example is a bit simpler than the code I am working with because there are 3 to 4 possibilities for each variable.

I am unfamiliar with many programming concepts and I have a feeling that there is already a good answer to this question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more specific to your particular case

Comment: what do you mean by possibilities?

Comment: Seems like this should get baked into a class that `foo` and `bar` uses.

Comment: I am working with a conjugation function for English verbs, so the variables are things like "time" (which can be "past", "present", or "future"), "tense" ("simple", "perfect", "progressive", "perfect_progressive"), "person" (1, 2, 3), and "plural" (True, False).

Comment: By possibilities I mean combinations.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24430421/3001761

Comment: Make a lookup table, as a dictionary of taking the combinations as a key or a tree with the node values as keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical Python replacement for lots of `if`s is a dictionary:

```
from functools import partial

def function(var1, var2, var3):
    choices = {(True, True, True): partial(foo, bar),
               (True, True, False): partial(bar, foo),
               ...}
    choices[tuple(map(bool, (var1, var2, var3)))]()
```

(In simple cases like this you could use `lambda` rather than [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)).

Or, in your case:

```
choices = {("past", "simple", 1, False): ..., 
           ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function(var1, var2, var3):
    def foo():
        pass

    def bar():
        pass

    func = {('past', 'simple', 'first', 'plural'): foo,
            ('past', 'simple', 'first', 'singular'): bar,
            ('past', 'simple', 'second', 'plural'): foo,
            ('past', 'simple', 'secord', 'singular'): bar,
            ...
            }[(var1, var2, var3)]
    func()
```